# Export to HAR File unsuccessful: Error while processing HAR file: j.n.c.lllegalCharsetNameException: "utf-8"

Tags: gatling

while doing the contact us scenario on http://automationpractice.com/index.php in Chrome:

1. click Contact us button
2. Fill the form - Subject Heading - Webmaster, Email address, Order reference, Message
3. click Send button
4. click logo button (Your Logo a new experience)
5. Save all as HAR with content

When I try to import it via Gatling recorder I get the message:

```
Export to HAR File unsuccessful: Error while processing HAR file: j.n.c.lllegalCharsetNameException: "utf-8". 
See logs for more information
```

[image]

Where are the logs to see more info about it?
Can someone help? What is the issue here? I couldn't find anything similar on the web.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/4094
Stephane Landelle solved it, but I don't know when will it be released